# How to write unit test to test deleting a record in a model

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I have a model, I would like to write a unit test to test delete operations on the model, I have written for create, read and update, but I cant seen to get a hang of how delete should work.
here is my code.

```py
def create_pay(self):

    pay = Pay.objects.create(user=self.user, amount=2000, appointment_count=2)
    return payout
```

here is were I call the create_pay method to test for delete operation

```py
def test_payout_model_delete(self):
        payout = self.create_payout()
        get_payout = Payout.objects.get(pk=payout.pk)
        del_pay = get_payout.delete()
        self.assertEqual(del_pay, (None))
```

But it gives me this error
AssertionError: (1, {'doctors.Payout': 1}) != None

Comment: The `delete` method returns a tuple with the total number of objects deleted, followed by dictionaries of models and the number of instances deleted. In your case, you successfully deleted one `Payout` object, so `(1, {'doctors.Payout': 1})` was returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requery the record and use exists() to validate that is no longer exists.

```py
def test_payout_model_delete(self):
   payout = self.create_payout()
   pk = payout.pk
   get_payout = Payout.objects.get(pk=payout.pk)
   del_pay = get_payout.delete()
   self.assertFalse(Payout.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count instead of delete method return type,

```
def test_payout_model_delete(self):
        payout = self.create_payout()
        payouts_len = Payout.objects.count()
        get_payout = Payout.objects.get(pk=payout.pk)
        get_payout.delete()
        self.assertEqual(Payout.objects.count(), payouts_len - 1)
```